# How do I assign an interface type to Array<object> returned from an API

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm new to both typescript and react. I have a React app that returns values from a REST call to a database API. I'm using a 3rd party library that calls the API and returns the results. As a simplified example the results are defined by an interface in library (that I have no control over) like this:

```
interface Response {

    results: Array<object>

}
```

I assume the library does this because the results returned are based on the structure of the table that is user defined which the library authors couldn't know. My question is assuming I know the structure of the table how would I assign (typecast?) the results returned to an interface I defined?

For example, if I know the results of the object inside the Array could be defined as:

```
interface MyResults {

    name: string
    age: number
}
```

ideally I'd like to so something like this in JSX:

```
return(

{results.map((item: MyResults) => <div>{item.name}</div><div>{item.age}</div>

)
```

When I try this though I get an error like this:

```
Argument of type '(item: MyResults) => React.JSX.Element' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: object, index: number, array: object[]) => Element
```

Comment: Does it give you the option to override the `object` type via generic? (eg object is the default value if you don't specify)

Comment: I'm not sure, and I'm still figuring out typescript. What that would look like? It seems that would make sense for a library. I did accept Andrei's answer below; which seemed to work for my purposes.

Comment: something like `const result = await yourFetchCall<MyResults>();`

Comment: I'm not seeing anything like that, but it makes sense that would be an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use assertion:

```
(results as MyResults[]).map((item) => (
  <>
    <div>{item.name}</div>
    <div>{item.age}</div>
  </>
));
```

Comment: This did the trick. Thank you! I wasn't sure where to do the assertion.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is in the jsx component

```
return(

{results.map((item: MyResults) => <div>{item.name}</div><div>{item.age}</div>

)
```

your problem could solved with this code

```
        return(
        <div>

        {
results.map((item: MyResults) => 
    <div key={item.name}>
    <p>{item.name}</p><p>{item.age}</p>
    </div>
)
    }
        </div>
        )
```

in your case you can  transform the Response in your custom object response as long as the properties match